# Ruby on Rails Model method error with has_many associations(revised)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Before I ask the question, I will describe the nature of my app and problem. The app consists of 3 models and all have has_many and belongs_to association with each other. However, our problem is only with the Scoreboards Model and Teams Model. 
Below are the model files for all three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :scoreboards, dependent: :destroy
end

class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :teams
 end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scoreboard
end
```

The following code contains the migration files for scoreboard and teams in case they're needed:

```
class CreateScoreboards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :scoreboards do |t|
      t.string :name_of_scoreboard
      t.string :name_of_organization
      t.string :name_of_activity
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :scoreboards, :users
    add_index :scoreboards, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end



class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :win
      t.integer :loss
      t.integer :tie
      t.references :scoreboard, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :teams, :scoreboards
  end
end
```

Below are the scoreboard and teams controller files. The scoreboard controller makes the associations to the user model which is not the cause of concern.

```
class ScoreboardsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index]
 before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]

 def new
   @scoreboard = Scoreboard.new
 end

 def create
  @scoreboard = current_user.scoreboards.build(scoreboard_params)
  if @scoreboard.save
   flash[:scoreboard] = "Scoreboard created successfully"
   redirect_to scoreboard_path(@scoreboard)
  else
   render 'new'
  end
 end

 def show
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
 end

private

  def scoreboard_params
   params.require(:scoreboard).permit(:name_of_scoreboard, :name_of_organization, 
                  :name_of_activity, :starts_at, :ends_at, :cities, :states, :country, :picture ) # make sure the name of the parameters match with 
                                     # the exact names written in the scoreboard model.
  end

end
```

The following is the teams controller:

```
    def new
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:id]) 
     @team = @scoreboard.teams.build
   end

   def create
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:id])
     @team = @scoreboard.teams.build(team_params)
     if @team.save
       flash[:success] = "Saved Successfully"
       redirect_to scoreboard_url(@team.scoreboard_id) #redirecting it to the scoreboard url associated with that team
     else
       render 'new'
     end
   end
```

teams form

```
<div class="team-contain">
   <%= form_for(@team) do |f| %>

         <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

         <%= hidden_field_tag :scoreboard_id, @scoreboard.id %>

         <%= f.label :name  %>
         <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"  %>

         <%= f.label :win %>
         <%= f.number_field :win, class: "form-control" %>

         <%= f.label :loss %>
         <%= f.number_field :loss, class: "form-control" %>

         <%= f.label :tie %>
         <%= f.number_field :tie, class: "form-control" %>


         <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

         <% end %>
</div>
```

We have associated the scoreboard model with the teams model where a scoreboard has_many teams and each team belongs_to a scoreboard. Once that association is written, the scoreboard class automatically has methods available for building the relationship between scoreboard and teams. As seen in the teams controller above, the method used in the create action was `@team = @scoreboard.teams.build(team_params)`. This method should create a has_many association between scoreboard and teams. However, the problem is that I get an error `"Undefined method "teams" for nil class"`. I am not sure why I am getting this because once the associations are made the `@scoreboard.teams.build` method should automatically be available. Also, the class isn't nil. The scoreboard class is defined in the model. I am really not sure why I am getting this error. I have read the association guide on ruby on rails. Based on that, this code should work. I am not sure what I am missing.

Also, how do we know that teams are related to that specific scoreboard. For example, the user could have many scoreboards. How do we make sure that the primary key of that specific scoreboard is the foreign key of the teams. Basically, how do we make sure that each team "1" is associated with a specific scoreboard "A" and not scoreboard "B". Is it possible to find the scoreboard `by_id` and save it to something like `@relevant_scoreboard` Or the Associations automatically take care of this. Any clarification on this point would be really helpful. 
I hope I have made myself clear with the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `@scoreboard` is nil, you've not set it.  If you're using nested resources you can do `@scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])`

Comment: @japed, I am using regular routes for teams. The code in route files for teams is "resources :teams". How would I create nested routes for teams which are nested inside scoreboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As seen in the teams controller above, the method used in the create
>   action was "@team = @scoreboard.teams.build(team_params)". This method
>   should create a has_many association between scoreboard and teams.
>   However, the problem is that I get an error "Undefined method "teams"
>   for nil class"

You haven't initialized `@scoreboard`, so `@team = @scoreboard.teams.build(team_params)` doesn't work. Defining it like `@scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])` should solve your problem.

> Also, how do we know that teams are related to that specific
>   scoreboard. For example, the user could have many scoreboards. How do
>   we make sure that the primary key of that specific scoreboard is the
>   foreign key of the teams

With the ***foreign_key*** `scoreboard_id` available in `teams` table you can get the teams associated with specific scoreboard by calling `@scoreboard.teams`.

For example, assume you have the following code

```
@scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(1)
@scoreboard.teams #will return the teams associated with it.
```

Also I recommend you to check these [***guides***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for your better understanding on how the things work behind the scenes.

Comment: First of all, thank you for you answer. After I insert the code   @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id]), I still get the following error. Active Record::RecordNotFound in TeamsController # Create couldn't find Scoreboard without an ID. raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{@klass.name} without an ID"

Comment: @kpaul Can you update your question with form code. You are not passing `scoreboard_id` to the controller.

Comment: I revised the question with the updated teams controller.

Comment: @kpaul Pavan means can you post your code from the view, with the form in it.